# Разбить текст на строки (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Ситуация следующая: мне приходят адреса автосалонов, которые выводятся над картой, таким образом

```
Новгород Пожарского 18 
Новгород Холодный 15 
Новгород Грузинская 11
Новгород Бояна 9
```

Мне нужно разбить текст на строки с помощью JavaScript.

Функция `search_result` содержит вывод этих адресов, но всё это впихивается в один балун, а надо, чтобы на карте были показаны все эти адреса. Вот как она реализована:

```
   function get_mark(){
        var mark = $('#mark').val();

        var city = 'Новгород';

        $('#search_result').load('/contacts/get_address.php?label_id='+mark+'&city='+city,{},function(){
            var content = $('#search_result').html();

            var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content);    // THIS! IS! АДРЕС!!!

            YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {
                var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), {style: style});
                map.setCenter(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
                placemark.description = "<span class='underline'>Автосалон</span><br>Адрес: "+content;
                map.addOverlay(placemark);
            });           
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
var content = $('#search_result').html().replace('\r','').split('\n');
for(var i = 0, il = content.length; i < il; ++i){
    //ставим метку. адрес - content[i]
}
```

Цикл for, если я правильно понимаю, нужно убрать в `function(geocoder){...}`, чтобы циклом добавить меток.

**Добавлено**

```
<div id="search_result">
Новгород Пожарского 18<br />
Новгород Холодный 15<br />
Новгород Грузинская 11<br />
Новгород Бояна 9<br />
</div>
<div id="YMapsID" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
get_mark();
function get_mark(){
    var content = $('#search_result').html().replace('\r', '').split(/<br ?\/?>/);
    var map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
    for(var i = 0, il = content.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(trim(content[i])){
            (function(addr){
                var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content[i]); // adress
                YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {
                    var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint());
                    placemark.description = "<span class='underline'>Автосалон</span><br>Адрес: "+addr;
                    map.addOverlay(placemark);
                });
            })(content[i]);
        }
    }
    var cntr = new YMaps.Geocoder(content[0]);
    YMaps.Events.observe(cntr, cntr.Events.Load, function(cntr){
        map.setCenter(cntr.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
    });
    map.redraw();
}
function trim(s){return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'');}
</script>
```

Ну, хоть сам научился ставить метки. =)

Comment: Ничего не изменилось:

    YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {
        var content = $('#search_result').html().replace('\r', '').split('\n');
        for (var i = 0, il = content.length; i < il; ++i) {
    
            var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), {
                style: style
            });
            map.setCenter(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
            placemark.description = "<span class='underline'>Автосалон</span><br>Адрес: " + content[i];
            map.addOverlay(placemark);
        }
    });

Comment: Увы, в API Я.Карт я еще не силен. Что делает строка `var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content); // THIS! IS! АДРЕС!!!` ?

Comment: Туда передается адрес. В данном случае туда передается Новгород Пожарского 18 
Новгород Холодный 15 
Новгород Грузинская 11
Новгород Бояна 9

Comment: Если создать несколько YMaps.Geocoder, будет несколько карт или несколько меток?

Comment: Каким именно образом?

Comment: Добавив в цикл `var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content[i]);`

Comment: $('#search_result').load('/contacts/get_address.php?label_id='+mark+'&city='+city,{},function(){
var content = $('#search_result').html().replace('\r','').split('\n');
for(var i = 0, il = content.length; i < il; ++i){
var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content[i]);
YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), {style: style});
map.setCenter(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
placemark.description = "<span class='underline'>Автосалон</span><br>Адрес: "+content[i];map.addOverlay(placemark);});}});

Comment: Код сюда не влезал, запихнул таким образом. Не зараблотало, создался один балун и в нем адрес undefined